# <ExtendedData xmlns=''> was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize my object ExtendedData

```
<ExtendedData xmlns:SMseeder="http://seedmaster.ca/"><Static><SMseeder:FanSpeed>200</SMseeder:FanSpeed></Static><Dynamic><SMseeder:Bin1SeedRate>100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100</SMseeder:Bin1SeedRate><SMseeder:Bin2SeedRate>200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200 200</SMseeder:Bin2SeedRate><SMseeder:Bin3SeedRate>300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300</SMseeder:Bin3SeedRate><SMseeder:Bin4SeedRate>400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400</SMseeder:Bin4SeedRate><SMseeder:OpenersPackingPressure>500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500</SMseeder:OpenersPackingPressure></Dynamic></ExtendedData>
```

But i got the error  was not expected after searching i got my class changed a bit but still same issue

```
 [XmlType(Namespace = "http://seedmaster.ca/", TypeName = "SMseeder")]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ExtendedData", Namespace = "http://seedmaster.ca/", IsNullable = false)]
public class ExtendedData
{
    [XmlElement("Static")]
    public ParamConfig StaticData { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Dynamic")]
    public SeedPlanWayPoint PlanWayPoint { get; set; }
}

 [XmlRoot("Static")]
public class ParamConfig : Seeder.Common.IParamConfig
{
    #region Variables
    private ILog _logger;

    [XmlElement("SMseeder:FanSpeed")]
    UInt16 _auto_fan1_rpm;
```

}

```
[XmlRoot("Dynamic")]
public class SeedPlanWayPoint
{
    [XmlElement("SMseeder:Bin1SeedRate")]
    public float Bin1SeedRate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("SMseeder:Bin2SeedRate")]
    public float Bin2SeedRate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("SMseeder:Bin3SeedRate")]
    public float Bin3SeedRate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("SMseeder:Bin4SeedRate")]
    public float Bin4SeedRate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SMseeder:OpenersPackingPressure")]
    public float OpenersPackingPressure { get; set; }

    public SeedPlanWayPoint() { }
}
```

Comment: You do not put the namespace in the [XmlElement].  You add to the [XmlRoot]

Comment: how the syntax should look like ?

Answer (score 1):

The namespaces should be declared like this

```
  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Dynamic", Namespace = "http://seedmaster.ca/")]
    public class SeedPlanWayPoint
    {
        [XmlElement("Bin1SeedRate")]
        public float Bin1SeedRate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Bin2SeedRate")]
        public float Bin2SeedRate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Bin3SeedRate")]
        public float Bin3SeedRate { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Bin4SeedRate")]
        public float Bin4SeedRate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("OpenersPackingPressure")]
        public float OpenersPackingPressure { get; set; }

        public SeedPlanWayPoint() { }
    }
```